# 'this' keyword not working

Tags: java, android

I created some `ImageView`s using a `for` loop and inserted them into a `ScrollView`.

Then I need to create one more `ImageView` when on touching the screen.
The `this` keyword cannot be used for creating an `ImageView` at the '###' marked position.

I am a beginner.

```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ScrollView scroll=new ScrollView(this);

        final LinearLayout layout =new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lparams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
        lparams.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;

        int i;

        for(i=0;i<15;i++) {
            //here 'this' is working   ******************
            ImageView imView = new ImageView(this);
            imView.setLayoutParams(lparams);

            Drawable new_image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rakthasakshi);
            imView.setBackgroundDrawable(new_image);

            layout.addView(imView, lparams);

        }
        scroll.addView(layout);
        setContentView(scroll);

        scroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    //but here says 'this' cannot be applied ###############
                    ImageView imView = new ImageView(this);  
                    imView.setLayoutParams(lparams);

                    Drawable new_image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rakthasakshi);
                    imView.setBackgroundDrawable(new_image);

                    layout.addView(imView, lparams);

                    scroll.addView(layout);
                    setContentView(scroll);

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ImageView imView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);`.

In the first case, `this` refers to `MainActivity` already.

However, in the second case, `this` actually refers to `View.OnTouchListener`.

Comment: thanks a lot ...it worked ..:-) i knew its a kind of reference but didnt know how exactly to work with it..

Answer (score 2):

Do you realise what `this` means in your context?

`this` references an anonymous class of type `View.OnTouchListener`.

To reference the object of your class `MainActivity` you have to reference `MainActivity.this`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a final context which have this and use it.

Example:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ScrollView scroll=new ScrollView(this);
        final Context ctx = this;

...


        //but here says 'this' cannot be applied ###############
        ImageView imView = new ImageView(ctx);
```

Answer (score 1):

This keyword works well in the parent class, but as you create child classes, you have to use `ActivityName.this` instead of `this`.